# How to get comboBox for a specific cell in gridControl

Tags: c#-4.0, row, cell

I need to get the comboBox for a specific Cell. How to do it. I tried but i cann't do this. I can't understand  what is the problem in my code.

```
     if (Convert.ToInt32(ddlModule.SelectedValue) == 5 && _entryType == Constants.EntryType.ENTRY_TYPE_DAILY)
        {
            column = new GridColumn();
            column.Name = "Actual";
            column.Caption = "Actual";
            column.Width = 125;
            column.AllowEdit = true;
            column.Type = GridColumnType.Int32;
            foreach (GridRow row in gridControl.Rows)
            {
                if(GridRow.Rows[i].Cells[2])
                {
                column.Type = GridColumnType.EditableCombo;
                }
            }

            gridControl.AddColumn(column);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> First find current row.
>    Now find controls within row.
>    Find required control type from group of controls.

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(cont).NamingContainer;

int rowID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);

DropDownList dropdown = (DropDownList)row.Cells[0].FindControl("DropDownList1");
```

**Or**

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgvcmbcell = dataGridView1[1, 0] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
```

Comment: It's Not working.GridRow row = (GridRow)(cont).NamingContainer;

                int rowID = Convert.ToInt32(gridControl.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);

                DropDownList dropdown = (DropDownList)row.Cells[0].FindControl("DropDownList1");

Comment: I haven't IDE now, so i can't give you exact solution, you have to go step by step as shown in yellow block.